# String.Empty as DirectoryName of HttpPostedFileBase

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, flickr

I have a controller with action:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Add(Question container, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {

            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var clientPath=Path.GetDirectoryName(file.FileName);
```

and clientpath is `""`.

I need this because I don't want to save file at my server, but right away sending it to flickr

```
        string photoId = flickr.UploadPicture(clientPath, title, description, "", uploadAsPublic, false, false);
```

How can I get path of client file?

I'm using FlickrNet library btw.

Comment: Modern browsers won't send the full file path (due to security reasons) so you can't know where the file was located, just its name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send the file directly without first saving it on the server, just use the overloaded method:

```
string photoId = flickr.UploadPicture(file.InputStream, title, description, "", uploadAsPublic, false, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You say you want to send the file directly to Flickr but your code attempts to use the `clientpath` for this... even if it wasn't empty (which it is because of security!) your code would NOT work... because it would try to use a path which only exists on the client-side of your ASP.NET-app as if it were a path on your server...

What you attempt is AFAIK impossible - what is possible is this:

IF FlickrNet library provides an `UploadPicture` method accepting a `Stream` then you can call it with `file.InputStream`... IF it does not provide such an overload you will have to save the file locally on your server in order to upload it to Flickr!